# Get the value from two cells and sum it and display in another cell using C# in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I want To the calculation inside the grid-view itself.The column1 and column2 display the data ,so in columns 3 it should subtract column2-column1.Column1 and column2 are manual entry only.My question is when the data is entered in both the column the value should reflect in the third column automatically.any idea for this,i didn't try any code for this,i am looking for in which event i have to write the code.

Comment: Are you using any kind of DataBinding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            int row = Convert.ToInt32(grid_calc.SelectedIndex.ToString());
            object value = (this.grid_calc.Items[row] as DataRowView)[2];
            object value1 = (this.grid_calc.Items[row] as DataRowView)[3];
            int a = Convert.ToInt16(value);
            int b = Convert.ToInt16(value1);
            int c = a - b;
            (this.grid_calc.Items[row] as DataRowView)[4] = c;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common scenario in WPF and the simplest solution would be to perform the calculation in a data type class rather than in the `GridView`. In WPF, we like to create custom classes that implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to hold the properties of our data, rather than using `DataTable`s and data bind collections of those classes to the `ItemsSource` property.

So if you had a class that represents your data, you could simply add another property to data bind to your third column. Let's say that your custom class properties are named `Column1`, `Column2` and `Column3`. Your properties should look like this to automatically update the third column:

```
public int Column1
{
    get { return column1; }
    set 
    {
        column1 = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Column1"); 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Column3"); 
    }
}

public int Column2
{
    get { return column2; }
    set 
    { 
        column2 = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Column2"); 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Column3"); 
    }
}

public int Column3
{
    get { return Column2 - Column1; }
}
```

If you are unfamiliar with data binding, you can find out more about it from the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need an event listener to see if your values in the grid view have changed

so

```
this.mygridview.CellEndEdit += mygridview_CellEndEdit;
```

then in the event handler

```
protected void mygridview_CellEndEdit(object_sender, EventArgs e){
int row_changed = this.mygridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
int column1_value = Convert.toInt32(this.mygridview.Rows[row_changed].Cells[0]);
int column2_value = Convert.toInt32(this.mygridview.Rows[row_changed].Cells[1]);
this.mygridview.Rows[row_changed].Cells[2].Value = (column2_value - column1_value ).toString;
```

All you need to do is check that both columns have numbers and are not null...
Just remember that your values will be refreshed if you have some postback or if the gridview has a datasource and the values refresh.. so just be careful..

Comment: Jonny-i am getting error in the mygridview.Rows[row_changed].Cells[0].the Row is not coimg.,

Comment: My apology. It should be 
Convert.toInt32(this.mygridview.Rows[row_changed].Cells[0].Value.toString())

Comment: i tried like this                                             DataRowView row = (DataRowView)grid_dc.SelectedItems[0];
            int col1 =int.Parse( row.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString());
            int col2 =int.Parse( row.Row.ItemArray[2].ToString());
            int col3 = col1 - col2;. now how can i update the col3 value into the column 3.

Comment: this.mygridview.Rows[row_changed].Cells[2].Value = (col3).toString();

Comment: after the gridview name,the Row is not taking,its not coming in the intellisense also.

Comment: From your sample, you can possibly try  row.Row.ItemArray[3] = col3

Comment: @Johny-i am not getting the answer,can help me out of this,i am end of the project.,